# Android set repeating alarm for certain time of day

Tags: android, intervals, repeatingalarm

I am trying to set a repeating alarm that will will download a file every minute but only between 8:00 and 22:00. I feel like I'm really close but I can't see the error I'm making. Currently the broadcast receiver is not activating. If set the repeating alarm manually to **alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, 60000,pendingIntent);** it works fine. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
protected void scheduleNextUpdate()
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent("TEST");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int updateInterval =  1;
        long nextUpdate =(60000 * updateInterval);

        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();


        long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + nextUpdate;
        Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
        nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

        if (nextUpdateTime.hour < 8 || nextUpdateTime.hour > 22)
        {
          nextUpdateTime.hour = 8;
          nextUpdateTime.minute = 0;
          nextUpdateTime.second = 0;
          nextUpdateTimeMillis = nextUpdateTime.toMillis(false) + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        }

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, nextUpdateTimeMillis,pendingIntent);

        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
                new Intent("TEST"), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (alarmUp)
        {
            Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set your alarm reapeating when it is between 8:00 and 22:00 like you mentioned:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, 60000,pendingIntent);
```

This will repeat every minute. But you must explicitly cancel the alarm. You can cancel it after download is completed, by checking if its already 22:00. Or by another alarm that will be triggered when it is 22:00. Otherwise it will not stop.

use `alarmManager.cancel (pendingIntent)`

described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent

Hope this helps.

Comment: So should put in an if statement ie,if(nextUpdateTime.hour >= 8){alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, 60000,pendingIntent); } if (nextUpdateTime.hour > 22){cancel (PendingIntent operation)}

Comment: Use like this: `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` However note that your `scheduleNextUpdate()` method should be called periodically. So you need one more alarm that calls it or checks for the hour. Then you can cancel your alarm

Comment: As a workaround I have the alarm repeating every minute but in the broadcast I have if/else statments to determine whether or to download the file within the certain time period. Im not sure if this is good practice but it works....